# how will i make the equal method in a class and how will i call that method to the main if that class was an abstract class

Tags: methods, equals

We were given a problem about subscribing and i was able to run it already but my only problem was i wasn't able to call my equal method for the reason of not knowing how. The problem says that if a user will enter an address the other user must not enter the same address and the equal method will verify if that address is already existing.

here is my equal method .. (is my equal method correct?)

```
public boolean equals(NewsPaperSubscriber address){
    return getStreetAdd() == address.streetAdd;
}
```

}

Comment: Use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` methods for comparing `String`'s in `Java`

Answer (score 0):

A little more of your code would help, but from what I see:

There are a few things to note on the code you posted.

Firstly, I'm assuming that the getter `getStreetAdd()` returns the `String` variable `streetAdd`. In that case, then why not use the getter for the object `address` as well? Not using the getter means your `address` field is `public`, make it `private` instead then use:

`address.getStreetAdd()`

Secondly, `==` compares the object references themselves, not the value of whatever the object contains. Example:

```
String string1 = "abc"
String string2 = "abc"
return (string1 == string2) // will return FALSE, because string1 and string2
                            // point to different locations in memory
```

Therefore, you can use the `.equals()` method provided by the `String` class. Combining both these things, your code should now look like:

```
public boolean equals(NewsPaperSubscriber address){
    return getStreetAdd().equals(address.getStreetAdd);
```

}